# Создание файла в внутренней памяти

Tags: java, android

Задача следующая - нужно создать файл во внутренней памяти телефона.
Причем не в `/data/user/...,` а в определенном каталоге -  `"*память телефона*/Documents/file.txt"` и записать туда текст из TextBox.

В моей процедуре ошибки нет, запись из textBox в файл я делаю, только сам файл нигде не наблюдаю.Я не знаю как здесь - `fos = openFileOutput(  FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);` указать, что нужно выполнить запись в каталог - "*память телефона/Documents/ в файл `FILE_NAME` (значение `FILE_NAME = "file.txt"`).
Прошу помочь. Благодарю!

**P.S.** Прочитал очень много похожих тем, в том числе и на stackoverflow - ответа не нашел. В манифесте все permissions для internal st указаны.

```
public void saveText(View view) {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    File file = new File("/Documents", FILE_NAME);

    try
    {
        EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(id.save_text);
        String text = textBox.getText().toString();

        fos = openFileOutput( file.toString(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
        //String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fos != null)
                fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Начиная ресии эдак с 5.0 помимо указания пермишена в манифесте надо еще и диалоговое окно с запросом прав показать пользователю. Показывали?

Comment: нет. диалоговое окно пользователя я не показывал. я начинающий разработчик в android studio, можете разъяснить?

Comment: Используйте полный путь к файлу, а не относительный, т.к. вы не правильно указываете директорию, которой в корне попросту нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вполне вероятно, что на доступ к внешней памяти у Вашего приложения просто нет прав.

Укажите в манифесте права:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Если предполагается работа на Android 6 и выше, после этого перед сохранением в файл вызывайте стандартную проверку:

```
if ((checkSelfPermission(
                (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                && (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)                
        ) {
            String[] perm = new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,                
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE                
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(perm, REQUEST_ID_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
        }
```

Также было бы не плохо проверить сам факт создания файла и папки, в которой он находится через `exists` и если их нет создать.

```
File f = new File(path);
f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: На доступ к внешней памяти права есть. Главный вопрос в том - как создать файл в конкретном каталоге и потом записать туда текст из textBox?

Comment: "На доступ к внешней памяти права есть" - показало диалог и вы разрешили доступ? Если нет, вы не сможете создать файл. Если не уверены - удалите руками приложение с телефона и запустите заново, должно снова спросить

Comment: При отладки кода:  public void saveText(View view) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        File file = new File("/Documents", FILE_NAME);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } выдает ошибку - java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: Диалог не показывало. Я не устанавливаю приложение на телефон, запускаю через AVD Manager.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСтепанов, если Вы получаете `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`, это значит файл или папка, где он должен находиться не существует. Их надо сощдать. Кстати, у Вас в коде есть только инициализация файловой переменной, а создания файла нет. Пример создания файла и папок я добавил в ответе, если что.

Comment: Диалог показало - доступ разрешил, но файл так и не увидел.

Answer (score 0):

Всё! Решил.
Код прилагаю:

```
   public void saveNote (View view) throws IOException {

        String fN = FILE_NAME;
        EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById (id.save_text); // содержимое файла

        requestPerms();
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Каталог не доступен: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Каталог не доступен: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        // получаем путь к SD
        File sPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // добавляем свой каталог к пути
        sPath = new File(sPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ DIR_SD);
        if (!sPath.exists())
            sPath.mkdir();
        // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
        File sFile = new File(sPath, fN);

        try {
            FileWriter f = new FileWriter(sFile);
            f.write(textBox.getText().toString());
            // закрываем поток
            f.close();
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен"+ sFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void requestPerms(){
    String[] perm = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,perm,123);
    }
}
```